# Snort rules regex matching

Tags: regex, pcre, snort

I want to generate an event in snort whenever someone visits a URL structured like

```
site/year2015.pdf
site/year2014.pdf
:
:
site/year2000.pdf
```

Instead of writing multiple snort rules as more URLs will be added over years I thought of utilizing PERC. The rule is written as.

```
alert tcp any any -> any any(msg:"PDF is being downloaded"; pcre:"(/.*site\/year\d\d\d\d\.pdf)/i"; sid: 100003; rev:3;)
```

I tried many different ways of inserting the regex in the rule above but it always fails to parse it. The Regex is doing fine what I want it to do [here](http://regexe.com/). The whole thing starts to fail because it does not start cause of rule not being parsed.

Error received is

```
Error: /etc/snort/rules/assignment.rules Line 3 => unable to parse pcre regex "(/.*site\/year\d\d\d\d\.pdf)/i"
Fatal Error Quitting..
```

Comment: What's the error, where is the code?

Comment: what is the actual string that you're matching against?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The (slightly crazy) syntax is `pcre:"/regex/flags"`.  The parentheses you wanted to put in there are superfluous anyway.  You also need to escape any slash which is part of the actual regex, [like in the example](http://manual.snort.org/node32.html#SECTION004526000000000000000).

```
alert tcp any any -> any any(msg:"PDF is being downloaded"; pcre:"/.*site\/year\d\d\d\d.pdf/i"; sid: 100003; rev:3;)
```

... though probably you should remove the superfluous wildcard `.*` and add an anchor `$` at the end, and also escape the dot to make it literal.  You might also want to use a quantifier to specify exactly four repetitions of a digit.

```
alert tcp any any -> any any(msg:"PDF is being downloaded"; pcre:"/site\/year\d{4}\.pdf$/i"; sid: 100003; rev:3;)
```

Are you really sure you want the `/i` flag to make the match case-insensitive?

Answer (score 1):

As tripleee mentioned, your parentheses were misplaced... but I also think that it's worth mentioning that since these are *Perl* regular expressions, you have some flexibility in the delimiters that you're using for the regular expression:

The syntax

```
pcre:[!]"(/<regex>/|m<delim><regex><delim>)[ismxAEGRUBPHMCOIDKYS]";
```

indicates that instead of using the traditional `/` delimiter, you may use the `m` operator (short for 'match'), followed by alternate delimiters... I'm using `[` and `]` in this case:

```
msg:"PDF is being downloaded"; pcre:"m[site/year\d{4}\.pdf$]i"; sid: 100003; rev:3;)
```

This doesn't buy you much in this particular case (because you're only one directory deep), but a more deeply nested directory would quickly become unreadable with all of the escaped `/` characters.

Comment: Hmm... I am new to regex with Perl. And just the rule parsing was a triumph, but the rule is still not triggering any event. :(